# Problem with monotony table

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm writing in LaTeX a document on maths and I'm using tikz to produce a monotony table.
So far so good , except for a slight problem. The code I'm using is the following:

```
\documentclass{10pt}{article}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-tab}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,snakes,arrows,backgrounds}
\usetikzlibrary{scopes,svg.path,shapes.geometric,shadows}
\usetikzlibrary{fit,shapes}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections,backgrounds}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
 \begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tkzTabInit[espcl=3]{$x$ /1,$f'(x)$ /1,$f(x)$ /2}
 {$0$ , $1$, $+\infty$}%
 \tkzTabLine {d,+ , z,-  }
 \tkzTabVar{-D-/ / $-\infty$,+/$f(1)=0$ /,-/ $+\infty$ /}%
 \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{document}
```

Well , yes, it gets what I want except for the double line under zero . It only produces a single line, not a double line which indicates that zero is not within the domain of the function.

However, in Altermundus it seems that this is the correct code because in the image , well, it is a shown with a double line. What is wrong and how I can display that double line?

**Edit:** Added packages.

P.S: *There are maybe more packages than needed here but I certainly use all of them in my doc.*

Comment: Can you add code to make the example compilable?

Comment: You mean the packages I loaded?

Comment: Yes: there are several `tkz` packages, you know.

Comment: Take a look... I updated the question.

Comment: @Tolaso when i compile your code i get double lines. by way it \documentclass[]{}

Comment: I get a single line. I don't know what's wrong.. Sorry about the \documentclass[]{} .. put on hurry.

Comment: @touhami Hang on a minute, when you say you get double, that double line seems clearly or the lines are on each other presenting it as a single line?

Comment: Oh well... apparrently there is nothing wrong with the code I am running but with the properties of the pdf viewer LaTeX is running... I'll see what I can do with that..

Meanwhile , in the pdf (Acrobat Reader) i get the double line as wanted... so that is enough for me...

Comment: LaTeX does not run a pdf viewer, either good or bad. So its properties are consequently non-existent.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was a viewer issue (see other comments).

Comment: @PaulGessler OK... no problem.. it was not something related to tikz at the end.